# Importing draw2d in react causes jquery reference error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, draw2d-js

As soon as I add `import draw2d from "draw2d"` to my imports I get `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

I tried installing and adding jquery but still get same error...

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import draw2d from "draw2d";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file with any name, e.g. import-jquery.js

## import-jquery.js

```
import jquery from "jquery";

window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
```

## App.js

```
import "import-jquery";
import "jquery-ui-bundle"; // you also need this
import "jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.css";
import draw2d from "draw2d";
```

**EDIT:**

And don't forget to...

```
npm install jquery
npm install jquery-ui-bundle
```

Comment: Cheers Zohab. Just needed to correct the first import and thought I'd add the npm installs in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: ;) there you go. I already accepted as the answer. What about upvoting my question??

Comment: But why did you install `import-jquery` package when you can simply import `import-jquery.js`?

Comment: cus if I didn't install it then it wasn't there to be able to import it :)

Comment: Any idea when I get `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` when I call `new draw2d.Canvas("draw2dHolder");`?

Comment: @TedTrippin it depends on your code, can't tell just reading your statement. However, I would suggest you to not to use Draw2d since it is not being maintained well. I worked on this for something but it has some bugs and no community support. I would recommend using `fabric` JS which is easy to learn, you can achieve more complex functionalities using fabric.